# Need a custom shortcode

Tags: wordpress, attachment, shortcode

```
// Image shortcode
function shortcode_image( $atts = array(), $content = null) {
    $atts = $this->attributefix( $atts );

    // [img="Google's Favicon"]http://www.google.com/favicon.ico[/img]
    if ( isset($atts[0]) ) {
        $alt = $atts[0];        //Google's Favicon
        $img = $content;        //http://www.google.com/favicon.ico
        return '<img src="' . $img . '" alt="' . do_shortcode( $alt )  . '" />';
    }
    // [img]http://www.google.com/favicon.ico[/img]
    else {
        $img = $content;
        return '<img src="' . $img . '" />';
    }
}
```

by this short code when i put this in my post i can see the image 
[img]http:*//localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/57e2008e828da.jpg[/img]

but i want to show my image like this

[img]215[/img]

note:215 image id number

how can i do that?

is this possible?

Comment: is this PHP code?

Answer (score 2):

For This you can use wp_get_attachment_url() and pass attachment id to get url, I have made a little modification to your function with wp_get_attachment_url().

```
function shortcode_image( $atts = array(), $content = null) {
   $atts = $this->attributefix( $atts );

   // [img="Google's Favicon"]http://www.google.com/favicon.ico[/img]
   if ( isset($atts[0]) ) {
       $alt = $atts[0];        //Google's Favicon
       $img = $content;        //http://www.google.com/favicon.ico
       return '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_url($img) . '" alt="' . do_shortcode( $alt )  . '" />';
   }
   // [img]http://www.google.com/favicon.ico[/img]
  else {
      $img = $content;
      return '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_url($img) . '" />';
  }
}
```